# accessing redmine

Tags: apache-2.2, redmine

i just installed redmine in my ubuntu server..

when i try to access it from this address localhost/redmine its not found

but when i do this script/server -e production -p 3000 then access redmine here localhost:3000 its working..

any idea..

i have php also installed in my server

and here is the vhost of my redmine

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName redmine.localhost
        ServerAlias redmine
        DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine/public/

        ServerAdmin user@server.com
        LogLevel warn
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/redmine_error
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/redmine_access combined

        <Directory /var/www/redmine/public>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: \script/server -e production -p 3000\ runs redmine using the provided webrick webserver, which is why that works. If you want to use apache to serve your redmine, you need to do additional configuration (see the answers).

Answer (score 3):

Do you have [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) installed? That's the easiest way to start serving a Rails application with Apache. It's quick to install and you shouldn't need to modify your virtual host configuration.

Alternatively, you can configure Apache to load balance with a cluster of Mongrels. This route requires more configuration.